# Is it possible to modify 8-pin Christmas tree LED controller's functions?

Tags: led, pcb, pwm, eeprom, controller

**Intro**
I have an 8-function artificial Christmas tree. The 2-wire LEDs have eight different lighting settings. The control box of the tree has a pushbutton that I can depress to cycle through the settings. I want to change some of the PWM settings on some of the functions. Bottom line upfront, I'm wondering if it's possible and how I would approach modifying the controller to achieve different PWM characteristics.

**Context**
Here is the diagram of the tree. The circuit board is inside the Control Box:
[image: User Manual Diagram]

Here is the circuit board inside the control box and the chip that I believe is the controller (it's unmarked)

[image: Circuit Board]
[image: Controller (left?) & EEPROM (right)]

**Summary of Questions**

1. Is the unlabeled IC most likely the controller? Is it a PWM controller? How might I identify this IC?
2. If it is the controller, how can I read its contents? Does it have functions I can modify?

Really hope someone might be able to point me in the right direction because otherwise I'm at a loss for how to proceed. Please let me know if any part of the post is unclear or needs more detail. Thanks!

Comment: Unlikely to be possible to modify the controller. Chop the lights off, measure the current/voltage in both directions, and then build something to drive it with a PIC or Arduino to control it.

Comment: Given that the unmarked chip is connected directly to the EEPROM, it is either a microcontroller or tiny FPGA.  You could search for these in SO-8 size and maybe determine one from the other by pin-out, but even if you find the exact model, it will likely be code-protected and unreadable or unmodifiable.

Comment: It almost looks like there IC's markings have been covered up in with paint... Maybe you can get that off with acetone?

Comment: If you can identify the controller, and assuming the very high likelihood it's code-protected, you could consider buying another of the same (or similar possibly with more memory for you to play with) and then write your own code, but use all the existing driver hardware as-is.

Answer (score 1):

Realistically, your only option is:

1. Reverse engineer the whole board.
2. Work out what microcontroller they have used from the pinout.  There may be several common ones that would be compatible.
3. Buy a compatible one, and a programmer.
4. Program it to do whatever patterns you want.
5. Un-solder the old processor and solder the new one on.